Scattering matrix vs. unitary transformations
In quantum optics, the input/output bosonic modes at a beam splitter transform according to the scattering matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           a_1 \\
           a_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\begin{pmatrix}
           1 & 1\\
           -1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
           b_1 \\
           b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix}  \;.
$$
However, in the Heisenberg picture operators can be shown to transform as
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
           a_1 \\
           a_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} = U \begin{pmatrix}
           b_1 \\
           b_2 \\
\end{pmatrix} U^\dagger \;,
$$
where $U$ is the unitary beam splitter transformation.
My question in, what is the relation between this first and second interpretation?
I'm sure it can formally be explained by linear algebra, but I'm just missing the connection.
